# Changing color and alpha of actor doesn't work in Scene2D

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Changing color and alpha of actor doesn't work in Scene2D; scaleTo, moveBy work though. What can be the issue?

```
@Override
public void render(float alpha){
     stage.act(delta);

     table.setTransform(true);
     //works
     table.addAction(Actions.scaleTo(2.3f, 2.5f, 2f)));
     //does not work
     table.addAction(Actions.alpha(0.2f, 2f));
     //does not work either
     table.addAction(Actions.color(new Color(1f,1f,1f, 0.2f), 2f));

     stage.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method `render()` is called every time screen is going to be rendered. So your code starts actions from beginning every frame and nothing changes.

You should move these lines from `render()` method to other place (for example to `show()` method of the `Screen` object):

```java
 table.setTransform(true);
 //works
 table.addAction(Actions.scaleTo(2.3f, 2.5f, 2f)));
 //does not work
 table.addAction(Actions.alpha(0.2f, 2f));
 //does not work either
 table.addAction(Actions.color(new Color(1f,1f,1f, 0.2f), 2f));
```

Comment: @gogonapel i guess you should show us the code of the other `Action`s, that seem to work. Anyways, you should not add `Action`s inside the `render(delta)` or at least not every call to it, since it is called many times per second (at least 30 times, if you want a smooth game).